# alternative to End statement in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Procedure which calls a module. Something like this:

Procedure:

```
Sub Procedure()

    Module1.SubProcedure()

    If Global.Variable = "A" Then
        ...
    End If

End Sub
```

Module1:

```
Sub SubProcedure()

    If x then 
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf y then
        End
    End If

End Sub
```

Using 'End' resets the Global.Variable. Is there any alternative to 'End' Which would stop the execution of Procedure() and preserve the value of Global.Variable?

Comment: If you want to end the whole code execution, I don't think you can preserve GlobalVariable in the stack, you will need a database (or even a simple print into the spreadsheet, but not the stack if you want to end it). If you don't really want to end it, then you might need to slightly re-designing your code. Could you add some context of why you would like to end the run but keep the stack please?

Comment: Probably create a boolean variable say `Global.bProceed` to control the flow of `Procedure()` and `Module1.SubProcedure()`.

Comment: The normal way to do this is to use an `Exit Sub` statement...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Function instead of using a subprocedure and then return a boolean like this :

```
Function SubProcedure() as Boolean

    If x then 
        SubProcedure = false
    ElseIf y then
        SubProcedure = true
    End If

End Function
```

and add these line to the procedure code :

```
if module1.subprocedure then
   End
end if
```

Comment: The "return" statement will give you an error in VBA.

Comment: No problem, I guess you develop C# / VB.NET, I always fall into the same trap ;) However, I think the user wants to stop the code execution, not returning to the caller Sub. Even if I would honestly re-design the code not too much differently than what you did.